# ReactJS semantic ui dynamically generated Breadcrumb menu

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, breadcrumbs

I want to create a breadcrumb menu dynamically, but I'm having an issue.

```
breadCrumbs() {
    return (
        <Breadcrumb>
            {this.state.breadCrumbs.map((element) =>(
                <Breadcrumb.Section key={uuidv1()} link>{element}</Breadcrumb.Section>
                <Breadcrumb.Divider />
            ))}
        </Breadcrumb>
    )
}
```

The above code won't work because I need to wrap Breadcrum.Section and Breadcrumb.Divider in another element. I tried using `div` but then then the divs are stacked one on top of the other. How can I make react happy and wrap components without messing the layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Fragments** in React to group elements without adding extra elements to DOM.

In your case you can wrap your Section and Divider in a fragment without using a `<div>`

```
<React.Fragment>
    <Breadcrumb.Section key={uuidv1()} link>{element}</Breadcrumb.Section>
    <Breadcrumb.Divider />
<React.Fragment />
```